# Outlook Add-in regular expression works on body but not on subject

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I am trying to apply a regular expression to highlight order numbers on outlook. I did it for the body message, but it is not working for the Subject of the email. I tested the outlook online and desktop versions and both only work for the body.

```
    <Hosts>
            <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
                <DesktopFormFactor>
                    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="DetectedEntity">
                        <Label resid="contextLabel" />
                        <RequestedHeight>140</RequestedHeight>
                        <SourceLocation resid="detectedEntityURL" />
                        <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="And">
                            <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
                                <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" Highlight="All"   />
                                <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" Highlight="All" />
                            </Rule>
                            <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
                                <Rule xsi:type="ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch" PropertyName="Subject" RegExName="OrderNumber2" RegExValue="0*[1-9]\d{7,}"  Highlight="All" />
                                <Rule xsi:type="ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch" PropertyName="BodyAsPlaintext" RegExName="OrderNumber" RegExValue="0*[1-9]\d{7,}"  Highlight="All" />
                            </Rule>
                        </Rule>
                    </ExtensionPoint>
                </DesktopFormFactor>
            </Host>
        </Hosts>
```

This is how my code currently looks like.

Answer (score 1):

We only support the use of "Highlight" in the case of the "ProperyName" being set to BodyAsPlainText. You can find the documentation on this [at this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/manifest/rule?view=common-js-preview#rulecollection:%7E:text=is%20all.-,Note%3A%20You%20must%20set%20the%20PropertyName%20attribute%20to%20BodyAsPlaintext%20if%20you%20specify%20the%20Highlight%20attribute%20for%20the%20%3CRule%3E%20element.,-Example).

Comment: Thanks for the response, is there a way to make the subject matching word clickable even if not highlighted? TIA

Comment: In other words, does the ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch work for ProperyName="Subject"? TIA

Comment: Yes, ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch works for PropertyName = Subject and you can get the matched regex using Regex API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messageread?view=outlook-js-preview#outlook-office-messageread-getregexmatches-member(1))